# How can i put part of a div inserted in a div outside?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs like this image:

[image]

Two of those divs have the same width and height and the last one (red div) should go outside but not all, only a part (10%) I tried `margin-left: -10px;` but it didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure negative margin works, for block elements. Maybe get a working example of your problem in http://jsfiddle.net/ and post here?

Comment: This Before -> normal After -> With margin-left negative and z-index http://imgur.com/nJsDl

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pmc7B/1/ this with my code

Comment: That is **my** code. Remember to save, and then copy the new url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have set `overflow: hidden` on one of the outer divs. That’s why the inner div is clipped when you apply the negative margin.

Comment: But ¿How can i put now an overflow:hidden;? :S

Comment: @MiguelBeltranSanz You were probably using `overflow: hidden` as a so-called “clearfix”. There are a few other ways to perform clearfix, ranging from floating the container, through various nitfy tricks, to adding the good-old `<div style="clear: both"></div>` to the bottom of the container.

Answer (score 1):

Try using absolute positioning and assigning a [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Please do not use absolute positioning when your problem does not require it.

Negative margin should be enough: http://jsfiddle.net/pmc7B/1/

Answer (score 0):

Give the parent `<div>` relative position:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
```

Then give the red `<div>` negative left value:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: -20px;">
```

Answer (score -1):

I think I see what your trying to do.  Have you considered giving the red div a Z index of +1 so it float over the others and acts independantly of them